# How to include data and two functions in my R package

Tags: r

I have installed "devtools" and "usethis" package. R version 3.6.2
The "devtools" has no problem creating package, and I have no problem load the data into a variable.
However when I want to use usethis::use_data(datasetname) then I receive errors like:

restarting interrupted promise evaluationError: Path 'E:/my_hard_drive/folder/datasetname' does not appear to be inside a project or package.

I do not know how to go "inside a project or package-- as I thought I am in.
My package structure is created by devtools, inside of my package folder, there is "description" and "namespace" and the .Rproj file, and "data" folder, "R" folder, and "man" folder (which is empty)

Did I miss something basic?

Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: You usually put it into a folder in your repository such as `inst/extdata` or just `data`. You can then easily access the path to your dataset with the `system.file` function.

Comment: while I am trying to run > roxygen2::roxygenize('.', roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace')) I also get:
Error: `package.dir` must include a DESCRIPTION file:
  * "myhardrivepath/folder" does not.
Did you call `roxygenize()` in a directory that is not the package root. How do I get to the package root? I tried setwd(), did not seem working.

Comment: I would recommend reading [R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) by the great Hadley Wickham before going any further. It goes over the structure of a package and how to start building one.

Comment: @rpolicastro: I did put the a .rda file into the "data" folder. I am still confused on how to link the data to make the package use it.

Comment: will read the book & thank you for recommending